# Add Attachment In Magento Email Model

Tags: magento-1.9, email, attachment

i would like to add the Attachment using below `Magento` model.

i have tried to add

```
$mail->getMail()->createAttachment(
    file_get_contents($fileName), //location of file
    Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'file.csv'
);
```

with below model.

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
    ->setToName($senderName)
    ->setToEmail($customerEmail)                    
    ->setBody($processedTemplate)
    ->setSubject('Subject')
    ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
    ->setFromName($senderName)
    ->setType('html')
    ->send();
```

It's Correct ? 
Any Help Much Appreciation! Thanks

Comment: @user1988065 sorry, not my question ;)

Comment: @mahmoudismail were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for sending mail with attachment

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('your_email_template');
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['var1'] = $var1;
$emailTemplateVariables['var2'] = $var2;
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('your_email_template');
$mailTemplate->setSenderName($name); // use general Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$mailTemplate->setSenderEmail($email); // use general Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')
$mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Subject :Bulkorder notification');
$mailTemplate->setTemplateText($processedTemplate);
// add attachment
$receivermail='aa@test.com';
$receivermail='AA AA';

      $mailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment(file_get_contents($csvfilename),
          Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
          Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
          Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
          $attachmentname
      );
    try{
            $mailTemplate->send($receivermail, $receivermail);
    }
    catch(Exception $error)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```